# Azure Logic App Run into "Cannot reach host runtime" Error

Tags: azure

I deployed a logic app standard in the Azure portal but it shows the below error

```
Cannot reach host runtime. Error details, Code: 'BadRequest', Message: 'Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime.'
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the service plan has to use Windows, instead of the Linux OS.

```
Note: Only the Windows-based App Service plan is supported. Don't use a Linux-based App Service plan.
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-azure-portal

BTW, worth mentioning, it could be the storage account connectivity issue, which can refer to below page, although it is not my case.

Reference:

[Storage Account Connectivity Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-diagnosing-failures?tabs=consumption)